# Can not run OSGi tests requiring "org.eclipse.pde.core" because of icu4j

Tags: java, testing, gradle, osgi, bnd

I am trying to run some test using the `aQute.bnd.gradle.TestOSGi` task from [bnd](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/).

My library requires `org.eclipse.pde.core`

```
Resolution failed. Capabilities satisfying the following requirements could not be found:
    [<<INITIAL>>]
      ⇒ osgi.identity: (osgi.identity=org.eclipse.pde.core)
          ⇒ [org.eclipse.pde.core version=3.13.200.v20191202-2135]
              ⇒ osgi.wiring.bundle: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.team.core)(bundle-version>=3.2.0)(!(bundle-version>=4.0.0)))
                  ⇒ [org.eclipse.team.core version=3.8.800.v20191122-2107]
                      ⇒ osgi.wiring.bundle: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.compare.core)(bundle-version>=3.5.200)(!(bundle-version>=4.0.0)))
                          ⇒ [org.eclipse.compare.core version=3.6.700.v20191122-2107]
                              ⇒ osgi.wiring.package: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.ibm.icu.text)(version>=3.6.1))
```

I have `'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:64.2'` as dependency and I even indicated that I would like to start the bundle `com.ibm.icu`.

```
-runrequires: \
    bnd.identity;id='${project.archivesBaseName}',\
    bnd.identity;id='junit-jupiter-engine',\
    bnd.identity;id='junit-platform-launcher',\
    bnd.identity;id='org.eclipse.pde.core',\
    bnd.identity;id='com.ibm.icu',\
```

Minimal reproducer project can be found here: [`pde-run` project on GitHub](https://github.com/jmini/bnd-experiments/tree/master/pde-run)

---

I looked at the MANIFEST file inside the `icu4j.jar`.

I see following:

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ICU4J
Bundle-Description: International Components for Unicode for Java
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.ibm.icu
Bundle-Version: 64.2

Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Main-Class: com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo
Export-Package: com.ibm.icu.lang,com.ibm.icu.math,com.ibm.icu.number,com.ibm.icu.text,com.ibm.icu.util
Automatic-Module-Name: com.ibm.icu
```

So `com.ibm.icu.text` is exported by this bundle.

Is there a way to understand what is going on?

I thought maybe the `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment` entry is preventing the bundle to be started (I am using Java 8 for my tests). If this is the case, what can I do to solve my issue?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unsatisfied requirement is package `com.ibm.icu.text` with `version>=3.6.1`. However the export from the copy of icu4j.jar that you have shown is unversioned, which means it has an implicit version of 0.0.0.

Unfortunately 0.0.0 is not greater than or equal to 3.6.1, therefore this bundle not satisfy the requirement from the `org.eclipse.compare.core` bundle.

Comment: Ok the icu4j jar on Maven Central (`com.ibm.icu:icu4j:64.2`) is not the same as the one you can download from the P2 update site `com.ibm.icu_64.2.0.v20190507-1337.jar`. The OSGi metadata are different.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the proper `com.ibm.icu` bundle from Eclipse Orbit. See https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/archive/reports/download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/index/com.ibm.icu_67.1.0.v20200706-1749.html, for example.

Comment: Absolutely… the OSGi metadata are not the same in the 2 places.

Comment: The linked resource is not available anymore.